# How to avoid GROUP_CONCAT() rows multiplying my SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a query who retrieves support tickets and with `GROUP_CONCAT()` im retrieving each ticket statuses on one row, to proccess in PHP as an array.

My problem is that on the query I have a `SUM()` to get time expent on each ticket from his interventions but, for example, if `GROUP_CONCAT()` retrieves 12 statuses and the ticket summation is 2400 seconds, the final result of `SUM()` is 2400 x 12 = 28800.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.subject as theme, SUM(fd.duree) as time, t.datec, t.date_close, t.category_code as category, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(tl.status, 0),'_',tl.datec ORDER BY tl.datec) as status
FROM llx_ticketsup as t
JOIN llx_societe as s on s.rowid = t.fk_soc
JOIN llx_user as u on u.rowid = t.fk_user_assign
JOIN llx_element_element as ee on ee.fk_source = t.rowid
JOIN llx_fichinter as f on f.rowid = ee.fk_target
JOIN llx_fichinterdet as fd on fd.fk_fichinter = f.rowid
JOIN llx_ticketsup_logs as tl on tl.fk_track_id = t.track_id
WHERE t.fk_statut = 8
AND t.fk_soc = 165
AND (STR_TO_DATE(t.date_close, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-06-25' AND '2018-06-25 23:59:59')
GROUP BY t.rowid
```

Result:

[image]

It should have 2400 on time, but is multiplying by his 12 statuses.

If I group by statuses too, time is well as you can see, but I need only one row with ticket real time expent and his statuses concatenated.

[image]

My question is, how can avoid `GROUP_CONCAT()` rows not to multiplying my `SUM()` ?

***EDIT:** I made it work by dividing `SUM(fd.duree)/COUNT(DISTINCT tl.rowid)`. I know it's a weird fix but don't know how to do otherwise. If anybody has any suggestion would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Roms, 
I think the value of 28800 in time, is not because of Group_Concat function, it is because you are using SUM() on it. It basically adds all values in "time" column for that group and displays it. If you want to keep the time constant by showing 2400 in the final result, you can replace SUM(fd.duree) as time by MAX(fd.duree) as time. This should fix it. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thanks for your answer. The case is that `SUM(fd.duree)` is the sum of each intervention of the ticket (one ticket can have one or more interventions). Time column is not directly on the ticket table. So thats the point doing `SUM()`. If I do `MAX()`, I have 1200 when 2400 is the correct number because this ticket has 2 interventions. If in the query I delete `GROUP_CONCAT()` column, the result is well (2400) but I need ticket statuses.

Comment: Push the group_concat into a sub query.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for you answer. What exactly do you mean to push into a sub query? Querying a `SELECT` inside first `SELECT` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.subject as theme, 
  SUM(fd.duree) as time, 
  t.datec, t.date_close, 
  t.category_code as category, 
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COALESCE(l.status, 0),'_',l.datec ORDER BY l.datec) 
    FROM llx_ticketsup_logs AS l WHERE fk_track_id = t.track_id) as status
FROM llx_ticketsup as t
JOIN llx_element_element as ee on ee.fk_source = t.rowid
JOIN llx_fichinter as f on f.rowid = ee.fk_target
JOIN llx_fichinterdet as fd on fd.fk_fichinter = f.rowid
WHERE t.fk_statut = 8
AND t.fk_soc = 165
AND (STR_TO_DATE(t.date_close, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-06-25' AND '2018-06-25 23:59:59')
GROUP BY t.rowid
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting real time * statuses row count (28800) as appear in the first image :/

Comment: Okay, what if you remove the JOINs to tables S, U and more importantly TL ?

Comment: Yeah, now is working! Thanks! So moving that `JOIN` into a `SELECT` subquery works well without multiplying aggregate functions per `GROUP_CONCAT` rows.